# MEAN Stack App: Getting results from backend database query, but frontend is saying that it can't get any results

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I have a MEAN stack app, most notably using Angular with a built in Express.JS backend. I've recently FUBAR'ed my local repo and rebuilt it from a clone of my remote repo, which doesn't include any of the changes I made to ruin my former repo and which is currently functionally deployed on Heroku. However, since I've cloned the repository, I've been having an issue where I am able to make a query directly to my backend with the "/api/monsters/" url and get the results from my database, but when the frontend attempts to do so it returns "Cannot GET /api/monsters".

Here is my Server.js file. This is the version that currently works in Heroku, but to get it working locally I've had to update distDir on line 12 to "var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/monster-playbook";". I also have to replace "process.env.MONGODB_URI" with the url of my database, which I can't post here or in my github repo because the url contains my login credentials.

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;

var MONSTER_COLLECTION = "monsters";

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Create link to Angular build directory
var distDir = __dirname + "/dist";
app.use(express.static(distDir));

// Create a database variable outside of the database connection callback to reuse the connection pool in your app.
var db;

// Connect to the database before starting the application server.
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI , function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    // Save database object from the callback for reuse.
    db = client.db();
    console.log("Database connection ready");

    // Initialize the app.
    var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080
        , function () {
        var port = server.address().port;
        console.log("App now running on port", port);
    });
});

// Generic error handler used by all endpoints.
function handleError(res, reason, message, code) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + reason);
    res.status(code || 500).json({"error": message});
}

app.get("/api/monsters", function(req, res) {
    console.log('attempted');
    db.collection(MONSTER_COLLECTION).find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get monsters.");
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(docs);
        }
    });
});

app.post("/api/monsters", function(req, res) {
    var newMonster = req.body;
    newMonster.createDate = new Date();

    if (!req.body.name) {
        handleError(res, "Invalid user input", "Must provide a name.", 400);
    } else {
        db.collection(MONSTER_COLLECTION).insertOne(newMonster, function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to create new monster.");
            } else {
                res.status(201).json(doc.ops[0]);
            }
        });
    }
});

app.get("/api/monsters/:id", function(req, res) {
    db.collection(MONSTER_COLLECTION).findOne({ _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) }, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
                handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get monster");
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(doc);
        }
    });
});

app.put("/api/monsters/:id", function(req, res) {
    var updateDoc = req.body;
    delete updateDoc._id;

    db.collection(MONSTER_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)}, updateDoc, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to update monster");
        } else {
            updateDoc._id = req.params.id;
            res.status(200).json(updateDoc);
        }
    });
});

app.delete("/api/monsters/:id", function(req, res) {
    db.collection(MONSTER_COLLECTION).deleteOne({_id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to delete contact");
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(req.params.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: Here's the code repo for this site: https://github.com/allredbm/Monster-Playbook.

Comment: Could you show your attempt to call the BE API from the client?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would show that in a way that could be posted to Stackoverflow. Do you know how I would do so?

Comment: Hmm. Showing things like what's going on in the **Network** tab could be useful in the first instance.

Comment: Everything in the Network tab seems to be as it should be. But a query is being made to http://localhost:4200/api/monsters with a status code of 404. This appears to be from the page's controller and is the failing query I mentioned above. When I query http://localhost:8080/api/monsters (which is the port that the backend is listening to), the response succeeds and I get all of the information I need.

Comment: So a request from the client is similar to this: `this.httpClient.get('/api/monster')`?
If so, try with: `this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/api/monsters')`; If that works, create a property in the  **environment.ts** file, let's call it `apiUrl` and assign `'http://localhost:8080'` to it. This will help you in the long run.

Comment: I've tried updating the url as you suggest, but it doesn't look like there is any change. The response from that method call is returning an error saying "Cannot GET /api/monsters"

Comment: Hm. Is the request made to: `http://localhost:8080/api/monsters`? If so and it still doesn’t work.. I have no idea

Comment: It's supposed to, but I don't know if the http request is actually reaching my backend. I just realized that I'd dropped a console.log into server.js, specifically at the start of the method that handles get requests to localhost:8080/api/monsters. When I query that url directly with Postman, I get a normal response. But when that http request is sent from my service, the console.log doesn't seem to get triggered.

Comment: I’m not sure what’s wrong..:/